# Update column based on another value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have questionairre data that has been exported to excel. i'm currently trying to clean the data but have a problem. It is numbered from 1.1 to 1.12 in the survey software however when it is exported to excel it changes 1.10 to 1.1.SO i end up with two questions both numbered 1.1. I'd like to be able to renumber the questions that should be 1.10

The data looks like this

```
data = [[1, '1.1', 'first'], 
       [1, '1.2', 'yes'], 
       [1, '1.1', 'daily'],
       [2, '1.1', 'last'], 
       [2, '1.2', 'yes'], 
       [2, '1.1', 'weekly']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['user_id', 'question', 'answer'])
```

I'd like it to look like this

```
data2 = [[1, '1.1', 'first'], 
        [1, '1.2', 'yes'], 
        [1, '1.10', 'daily'],
        [2, '1.1', 'first'], 
        [2, '1.2', 'yes'], 
        [2, '1.10', 'weekly']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['user_id', 'question', 'answer'])
```

I've tried this

```
if df[(df.question == '1.1')]:
    if df[(df.answer == 'first')]:
        df.question == '1.1'
    else:
        df.question == '1.10'
```

but get this error

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.loc[(df['answer']!='first') & (df['question']=='1.1'),'question'] = '1.10'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df['question'] = df.apply(lambda row: '1.10' if (row['question'] == '1.1' and row['answer'] != 'first') else row['question'], 1)
```

What we're doing is building a function with `lambda` which takes in a single row of your dataframe, returns '1.10' if the question is 1.1 and the answer isn't 'first', and returns the existing question value other wise. We then generate a column by applying that function to the dataframe, and repalce what we already have for question with that column.